# MySQL Trigger to change inserted text

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a trigger to my database that checks if a certain field of the inserted row contains a certain text, and if so, it inserts empty string. I've written this but it throws me an error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_abcdef BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.Body LIKE '%abcdef%' THEN NEW.Body = '' END IF
END
```

Can someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.Body = '' END IF END' at line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change the delimiter. Then use `set` to change the value

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER no_abcdef BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Body LIKE '%abcdef%' THEN 
       SET NEW.Body = '' ;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```