# MySQL trigger to replace specific characters on insert

Tags: mysql, replace, triggers, insert, character

i need to replace some of characters with alternatives while inserting to table, to be more specific i want to clear Turkish characters like "Ç Ş İ Ğ Ü Ö" while inserting. I'm able to do it with PHP before calling insert procedure but wondering is it possible to do with MySQL Trigger.

I've found this example [MySQL Trigger to change inserted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822863/mysql-trigger-to-change-inserted-text) and edited according to my need but when i tried, realised it only changes one letter and others remain the same, for example i've a string like "ÇARŞAMBADAN ÇARŞAMBAYA" it changes as "CARSAMBADAN ÇARŞAMBAYA" as you see it replaces first "Ç" and other character is remain.

Is it possible to replace specific characters with alternatives with MySQL Trigger ?

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER replace_tr BEFORE INSERT ON isimler
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Body LIKE '%Ç%' THEN 
       SET NEW.Body = '' ;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Or do you want to able easy search on `ÇAR` with `CAR` for example?

Comment: @RaymondNijland i'm just curious,as i mentioned i allready can with php but as you can imagine sometimes forms have so many variables and i need call replace function for each of them, i'm sure there is an easy way to do so but i'm just a senior developer, still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a series of assigments using `replace()` to replace characters.

```
...
BEGIN
  SET new.body = replace(new.body, 'Ç', 'C');
  ...
  SET new.body = replace(new.body, 'Ö', 'O');
END;
...
```